# Array out of Bound Crash

Tags: ios, arrays, crash

I am currently having an array out of bound issue and cannot find a way how to fix it.  I am suspecting from my crash reports that I am having a problem with this part of code. Any advice and how should I fix this problem?? Feel free to ask a specific code.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"a");
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *fileManager  = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    //configure carousel1
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tops"];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    imageArray1 = [directoryContent mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"%@", [imageArray1 objectAtIndex:0]);←This line is 70
    NSLog(@"1:::%d", [imageArray1 count]);

    //configure carousel2
    fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Bottoms"];
    directoryContent = [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath:fPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", fPath);
    imageArray2 = [directoryContent mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"2:::%d", [imageArray2 count]);

    carousel1.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
    carousel2.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;

    [carousel1 reloadData];
    [carousel2 reloadData];

    carousel1.delegate = self;
    carousel1.dataSource = self;
    carousel2.delegate = self;
    carousel2.dataSource = self;
}
```

**Update**

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2edecf4e __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x390986aa objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2ed235ee -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 226
3   Appname                         0x000acab8 -[iCarouselExampleViewController viewDidLoad] (iCarouselExampleViewController.m:70)
4   UIKit                           0x315625fe -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 514
5   UIKit                           0x315623bc -[UIViewController view] + 20
6   UIKit                           0x3160c632 -[UIViewController shouldAutorotate] + 22
7   UIKit                           0x31648d76 -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:] + 246
8   UIKit                           0x316476ae -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 2054
9   UIKit                           0x31646700 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 4664
10  UIKit                           0x31821656 -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 26
11  UIKit                           0x31592f3a -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 86
12  UIKit                           0x31592eda -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
13  UIKit                           0x31592eb4 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
14  UIKit                           0x3157eb3a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 370
15  UIKit                           0x3159292a -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 586
16  UIKit                           0x315925fc -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 524
17  UIKit                           0x3158d688 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 828
18  UIKit                           0x31562a20 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 192
```

Comment: Please add the crash report, the error message and show which line it points to in the above code.

Comment: I have added the crash report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to venture a guess, the directory is empty.

```
imageArray1 = [directoryContent mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@", [imageArray1 objectAtIndex:0]);←This line is 70
```

If `imageArray1` has no contents, line 70 will crash, just as your report shows. Rather than crashing, you should check `[imageArray1 count]` and only use it if there are values. Your code doesn't really do anything with these arrays here, but here's the structure that it should look like. You'll also need to do the same thing for carousel2.

```
//configure carousel1
NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tops"];
NSArray *directoryContent = [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
imageArray1 = [directoryContent mutableCopy];
if ([imageArray1 count] > 0) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [imageArray1 objectAtIndex:0]); //This line is 70
    NSLog(@"1:::%d", [imageArray1 count]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"No objects in imageArray1.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not share the output of the logs which would help, nor your delegate methods, which would help. That said, you should send reloadData as the very last message, after setting the data source and delegate - as good practice (it seems that lately iOS defers action until the end of the run loop ).